# Load data into tableview from web service in runtime

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableview and i have to load data(say contacts) into the tableview by hitting web service. The simple way is to get all the contacts from the web service and then load those data into tableview. That might require a loading screen during the webservice load time and then we can load all data into tableView. But in my scenario, i have more than 3000 contacts. So the service load time might be too long. How can i handle this situation. My idea is, at first i should get only some 50 contacts from web service under the loading screen. Then i should load the other contacts while scrolling the tableview without loading screen. How can i do this. Can anyone help me on this with some code?

Comment: @rmaddy: May i know y did u downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I did vote to close because your question is far too broad. You need to narrow your question down to a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Try pagnation in the web service to only send 50 contact in each page.then use by using SVPulltoRefresh u can add the contact to the end of the current table

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain pagination. Like in first request server will return only  first 50 records. Then when you scroll down your table to last row, you need to check that its a last row and start downloading new data (next 50 records) from server in background. As soon as data downloaded you need to reload table again.

Hope this help.